# What are the types of density matrix mixing methods?

Tags: density-functional-theory, one-topic-per-answer, optimization

I would like to know what are the different types of mixing procedures to be applied to the density matrix (Broyden mixing, Pulay mixing) and their pros and cons?

Comment: Just to check: do you mean density matrix mixing, or density mixing?

Comment: I believe it's density matrix mixing.

Comment: +1. If there's no answer within 24 hours of the bounty expiry, please remind me to come back here.

Comment: @NikeDattani I would like to inform you that there is no answer to the question yet.

Comment: The bounty also expired long ago!! Haha

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but now that it has been more than 1 year, can you update us please? Are you still urgently or actively in need of an answer to this question? Maybe you can write a self-answer for Broyden mixing?